# Payment Gateway integration in Hybris

Tags: integration, payment-gateway, sap-commerce-cloud

​Does anyone have the steps to integrate a Payment Gateway in Hybris? I need to integrate with K-Net.
Note: I won't be using any plugins for the Checkout page, need to develop it from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check some existing payment providers extensions. For example [adyen](https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-hybris).

Comment: I will be doing custom integration with K-NET and will be redirecting the user to their platform. I just wanted a guide or step wise documentation for the procedure in Hybris. @mkysoft

Comment: Adyen also make same thing. Generally all payment providers same logic.

Comment: I will be doing it from scratch and have everything ready on the Payment Gateway side. Have tested their APIs in Postman. I just need to add them in their required places. I wanted a flow which lets me know step wise how to do it.